# How to use subtype polymorphism & generics for lists?

Tags: generics, inheritance, java-8

I'm learning Java, and have read about inheritance and subtype polymorphism. Now I'm just starting to learn about generics, and I'm trying to put the pieces together, but am stuck.

Say I've an `abstract` parent class `AbstractEdibles`, and there are two children that `extend` from it: `Food` and `Drink`. Also, I've a `Store` that has two `List`s: one to store `Food` and one to store `Drink`.

Now, I want my `Store` to be able to have behaviors, such as adding to its stock. **My desired approach is to define one method to take in a product and put it in the appropriate list. If it's a `Food` type, put it in the food list. If it's of type `Drink`, put it in the drink list.**

I'm sure I need to use generics and subtype polymorphism. Here's a snippet of my code:

```
public class Store {

  private List<AbstractEdible> foodStock = new ArrayList<>();
  private List<AbstractEdible> drinkStock = new ArrayList<>();

  /**
   * A constructor for a new store inventory that has food and drink.
   *
   * @param foodStock   the list of food items in stock
   * @param drinkStock  the list of drink items in stock
   */
  public Store(List<AbstractEdible> foodStock, List<AbstractEdible> drinkStock) {
    this.foodStock = foodStock;
    this.drinkStock = drinkStock;
  }

  /**
   * Given an edible food, add it to its respective stock list.
   *
   * @param edible an edible item
   */
  public void addItemToStock(AbstractEdible edible) {
    if (product instanceof Food) {
      this.foodStock.add(product);
    } else if (product instanceof Drink) {
      this.drinkStock.add(product);
    }
  }
}
```

This doesn't give errors, but I'm unhappy with how loose I'm being with the types, and I think it could be made more optimal.

For starters, I'd prefer to allow my list to **only** allow that specific type of `edible`. That is, `foodStock` will only allow `Food` to be added, and `drinkStock` will only allow `Drink` to be added. What I tried was:

```
private List<AbstractEdible> foodStock = new ArrayList<Food>();
private List<AbstractEdiblet> drinkStock = new ArrayList<Drink>();
```

gives me a red underline in my IDE. So then I changed to:

```
private List<Food> foodStock = new ArrayList<Food>();
private List<Drink> drinkStock = new ArrayList<Drink>();
```

this works, but then my `addItemToStock()` method complains that the `edible` I'm trying to add is of type `Edible` and can't be added to a `List` containing type `Food`. (This is expected, because `Edible` is the parent of `Food`; i.e. not every `Edible` is a `Food`, but every `Food` is `Edible`.)

Up/Down casting `edible` doesn't help, either. I then thought [Upper Bounded Wildcards](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html) was what I was looking for, but that also didn't work.

Besides that, I'm also unsure if using `instanceof` is the best way to classify/sort objects.

What am I missing here? What concept am I not understanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to ensure that `foodStock` stores `Food` only and `drinkStock` stores `Drink` only, then you'll have to initialize your lists like this:

```
private List<Food> foodStock = new ArrayList<>();
private List<Drink> drinkStock = new ArrayList<>();
```

If they are coming from constructor, just declare them:

```
private List<Food> foodStock;
private List<Drink> drinkStock;
```

and then assign them in constructor:

```
public Store(List<Food> foodStock, List<Drink> drinkStock) {
    this.foodStock = foodStock;
    this.drinkStock = drinkStock;
}
```

And once you have used `instanceOf`, it is safe to use casting:

```
public void addItemToStock(AbstractEdible product) {
    if (product instanceof Food) {
        this.foodStock.add((Food) product);
    } else if (product instanceof Drink) {
        this.drinkStock.add((Drink) product);
    }
}
```

---

You could also create a generic `Stock` class:

```
public class Stock<T extends AbstractEdible> {

    private List<T> items;

    public Stock() {
        items = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addItem(T item) {
        this.items.add(item);
    }

    public List<T> getItems() {
        return items;
    }
}
```

and use it in your `Store` as:

```
public class Store {
    private Stock<Food> foodStock;
    private Stock<Drink> drinkStock;

    public Store() {
        this.foodStock = new Stock<>();
        this.drinkStock = new Stock<>();
    }

    public Store(Stock<Food> foodStock, Stock<Drink> drinkStock) {
        this.foodStock = foodStock;
        this.drinkStock = drinkStock;
    }

    public void addItemToStock(AbstractEdible product) {
        if (product instanceof Food) {
            this.foodStock.addItem((Food) product);
        } else if (product instanceof Drink) {
            this.drinkStock.addItem((Drink) product);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm, apparently I was close the first time. I tried casting, but I guess I didn't do it correctly the first time, as it didn't work. But your (first) method worked, thanks. And +1 for also including a second approach.